# Abort Trap: 6 error after upgrading to Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, compiler-errors

I just updated my Xcode to Version 14.1 (14B47b) from version 13.4. When I try to run my SwiftUI project in the live preview, the "Abort Trap" errors showed everywhere in the project.

Part of the error log is as below:

> CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/apple/Downloads/SwapSpot/SwapU/ViewModels/ItemVMs/ItemGridViewModel.swift (in target 'SwapU' from project 'SwapU')
>
> unknown:0: error: fatal error encountered during compilation; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project
>
> unknown:0: note: SmallVector unable to grow. Requested capacity (4294967297) is larger than maximum value for size type (4294967295)
>
> Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.

I found a post that answers as such:

> We will not observe "Abort: trap 6", if under Build Settings, we are using "Optimize for Speed" in Debug, instead of "No Optimization"
>
> We can also avoid "Abort: trap 6", if we change the following code
>
> `guard let batchUpdateResult = batchUpdateResult else { return }`
>
> to
>
> `guard let batchUpdateResult2 = batchUpdateResult else { return }`

I tried both methods mentioned above. Renaming the guard let variable did not work at all. Changing the optimization level in the target removed all the Abort Trap errors, and the project runs successfully in the simulator.

However, the live preview stopped working due to the optimization level. The new error is stated below:

> OptimizationLevelError: not building -Onone
>
> "SwapU.app" needs -Onone Swift optimization level to use previews

I believe this is a swift compiler error. Can anyone help me avoid this while keeping the live preview working?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have the same issue (as the error code isn't really telling), but I ran into the same error with the following code:

```
   func error(message: String) -> some Error {
      NSError(
         domain: String(describing: Self.self),
         code: -1,
         userInfo: [
            NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "\(Constants.appDisplayName): [\(String(describing: Self.self))] \(message)"
         ]
      )
   }
```

Then when I called this method, the build would pass successfully on DEBUG builds, but when trying to archive the project, it would fail with the aforementioned error.

The fix in my case was to replace the return type `-> some Error` with `-> NSError`. It seems, Swift got confused in type matching here.

While your case might differ, maybe you want to try commenting out some code calling into APIs returning `some` or `any` types (and simply returning `fatalError()` until you find the code that seems to get the compiler confused.

Good luck!